# Strange flickering with UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, webview, flicker

I have this strange (short) flickering when pushing a new viewController which contains a UIView > UIWebView.

Inside the controller.m, which contains the UIWebView, I have this code setup for the webView:

```
//EXAMPLE 1
```

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

NSString *htmlData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">* { margin:0; padding:0; }body { background-color:#c6c6c6; width: 320px; font-family: Helvetica; font-size:13px; line-height: 18px; color:#404a52; } #someOtherStyles...</style></head><body><div id=\"mededelingenDetailViewHeader\"><h1>%@</h1><p class=\"date\">%@</p><p class=\"author\">%@</p></div><div id=\"mededelingenDetailViewContent\"><p>%@</p></div><!-- mededelingenContent --></body></html>", titleString, dateString, authorString, filteredDescription ];

[webView loadHTMLString:htmlData baseURL:baseURL];

With this code the flickering shows up when pushing this controller onto the window. But if I change the htmlData to something simpler like the code below without for e.g. css the flickering suddenly dissappears.

```
//EXAMPLE 2

NSString *htmlData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body><h1>Some Header!</h1><p>Some text</p></body></html>"];
```

So is there a way to load an .html file inside my NSBundle and assign NSString to some HTML contents like I did with htmlData in example 1? Or is there any better way to do this?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Is `[webView loadHTMLString:htmlData baseURL:baseURL];` called from viewDidAppear? If so, that would explain the flicker: it's loading the HTML while the user watches. Move that call to viewDidLoad and see if that solves it.